# How do I normalize org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors?

Tags: scala, vector, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

It is pretty easy to normalize vectors in Scala (scala.collection.immutable.Vector) using map:

```
val w = Vector(3,4,5)
/** L1 norm: **/
val w_normalized = w.map { _/w.sum }
```

But you can't perform the same thing with org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector: if you try it, you get an error:

```
error: value map is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
```

So, what is a way to normalize spark vectors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34234817/1560062

Comment: this makes sense, thanks a lot! :)