# Easy way to center a column in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, centering

I want to center a column in a Spark DataFrame, i.e., subtract each element in the column by the mean of the column. Currently, I do it manually, i.e., first calculate the mean of a column, get the value out of the reduced DataFrame, and then subtract the column by the average. I wonder whether there is an easy way to do this in Spark? Any built-in function to do it?

Comment: [Feature normalization algorithm in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34234817/10465355)

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt function for this but you can use user defined function [ [udf](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs.html) ] as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
(2.06,0.56),
(1.96,0.72),
(1.70,0.87),
(1.90,0.64))).toDF("c1","c2")

def subMean(mean: Double) = udf[Double, Double]((value: Double) => value - mean)

def getCenterDF(df: DataFrame, col: String): DataFrame = {
val avg = df.select(mean(col)).first().getAs[Double](0);
df.withColumn(col, subMean(avg)(df(col)))
}

scala> df.show(false)
+----+----+
|c1  |c2  |
+----+----+
|2.06|0.56|
|1.96|0.72|
|1.7 |0.87|
|1.9 |0.64|
+----+----+

scala> getCenterDF(df, "c2").show(false)
+----+--------------------+
|c1  |c2                  |
+----+--------------------+
|2.06|-0.13750000000000007|
|1.96|0.022499999999999853|
|1.7 |0.17249999999999988 |
|1.9 |-0.05750000000000011|
+----+--------------------+
```